# Toggle between active content state

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

I'm building a React tab navigation component with emotion. I'm having trouble finding a solution that would allow me to:

- Initially hide all content except for the buttons and not style the buttons.
- When you click on a button activate the style and show the content associated with that button.
- And finally when you click outside or the input is empty reset to initial state.

Here is the code:
[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/active-react-tabs-issue-cq3rb?file=/src/index.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

import "./styles.css";

const StyledShowButton = styled("button", {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => ["active"].indexOf(prop) === -1
})`
  color: ${({ active }) => (active ? "red" : "black")};
`;

function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value < 1) {
      console.log("Reset Everyting");
    }
  };

  const handleTabClick = (e) => {
    const index = parseInt(e.target.id, 0);
    if (index !== active) {
      setActive(index);
    }

    if (!showInput) {
      setShowInput(!showInput);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledShowButton
        type="button"
        id={0}
        active={active === 0}
        onClick={handleTabClick}
      >
        First
      </StyledShowButton>

      <StyledShowButton
        type="button"
        id={1}
        active={active === 1}
        onClick={handleTabClick}
      >
        Second
      </StyledShowButton>

      {/* CONTENT */}
      {active === 0 ? (
        <input placeholder="First input" onChange={handleInputChange} />
      ) : (
        <input placeholder="Second input" onChange={handleInputChange} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Just ask if I didn't make my self clear enough,

Thanks beforehand!

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can hide inpts in this way at first by assigning a null value to the active state.
You can also initialize values ​​from 1 so that id and state state are not confused.
I made the arrangements.
You can review the code below.*

You can also view it from this link. [Code:](https://codesandbox.io/s/active-react-tabs-issue-forked-epnd2)

```
function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value < 1) {
      setActive(null);
    }
  };

  const handleTabClick = (e) => {
    const index = parseInt(e.target.id, 0);
    if (index !== active) {
      setActive(index);
    }
    if (!showInput) {
      setShowInput(!showInput);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledShowButton
        type="button"
        id={1}
        active={active === 1}
        onClick={handleTabClick}
      >
        First
      </StyledShowButton>
      <StyledShowButton
        type="button"
        id={2}
        active={active === 2}
        onClick={handleTabClick}
      >
        Second
      </StyledShowButton>
      {/* CONTENT */}
      {active &&
        (active === 1 ? (
          <>
            <input placeholder="First input" onChange={handleInputChange} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <input placeholder="Second input" onChange={handleInputChange} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```